# Stack Exchange login without prompt for credentials after logout?

Tags: bug, logout, auto-login

I am experiencing logout problems on security.stackexchange.com. After logging out  and restarting the browser the login page logs me in **without** asking for login/password.

Anybody seeing this? I tested using FF and IE.

Looks like some cookie is stored that 'remembers' login creds, but this doesn't look like I could access Stack Exchange on public computers.

Comment: If you signed up for StackExchange via Google Accounts or OpenID, you're getting signed in automatically via that.

Comment: My SE profile is associated only with SE account. Originally I established my StackExchange profile with Google ID, but then I added newly registered StackExchange account to my profile and removed Google account. Besides, my google login is session based so restart browser should clear any google account cookies.